# XML parsing info between the tags

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, android-xml

I have the following xml file

```
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"     xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Placemark>
<name>Simple placemark</name>
<description>Attached to the ground. Intelligently places itself at the
      height of the underlying terrain.</description>
<Point>
    <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
</resources>
```

how to read the numbers between the tags not the attributes ???

```
 <coordinates> -122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
```

I have this in the handler

```
XMLDataColleted info  = new XMLDataColleted(); 
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (localName.equals("coordinates")){
    double X = /// need help here how to get the number ; 
    double Y = // here also ?? ; 
    info.setx(X) ; 
    info.sety(Y) ; 
    }
    else if ( localName.equals("description")){
        String s = // the discreption // need help here; 
        info.setDis(s) ; 
    }
```

Comment: You also could use regular expressions, if you really only need this content?!

Comment: I didnt understand you ?? I am doing my first parsing xml application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SAX parser we have another overridden method:

```
@Override  

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) { 
     String chars = new String(ch, start, length); 
     chars = chars.trim(); 

     if(_inCoordinates) { 
          _data.coordinates = chars; 
     } 
}
```

You can check this [link](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example) for an example.

Comment: thanks but I still have some problems with the file, the tutorial that I am following is using URL but I have an xml file where should I place it ?? and how I can deal with it ?

Comment: Is this xml coming from server?

Comment: Note: what most beginners get wrong with the characters() callback is they assume all the data will be passed in a single call of characters(). There is no guarantee of this; the text can be split up into multiple calls any way the parser sees fit, and the application has to buffer it.